# JS: Get the var name

Tags: javascript

I have this code here:

```
var myVar = 'this is a string';
```

I want to get the string representation of the variable name myVar. This is a very simplified example. Obviously we know it's myVar but it demonstrates my need.

I need to run a function like this:

```
function getVarName(v) {
    return v.blah;
}
var nameOfVar = getVarName(myVar); //should  'myVar'
```

Is this possible? I'm not worried about cross-browser, it's for a firefox addon so I can use the latest >= ES5.

Thanks

Edit: I wanted to add the reason I was doing this, it was to dump some objects in firefox system, it helps me make addons. I know the key/value thing in objects, but in case the function gets run on a string or some non-object it would be nice to know the var name it got run on. It runs on bunches of stuff automatically so I don't know the var names.

Comment: Completely impossible. There is no way to get the name of a variable, especially after you've lost the variable completely. Any name you could get inside `getVarName(v)` would just be "v". The *name* of the variable isn't passed in, only its value.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?  This is not possible but maybe we can come up with a solution that doesn't need this.

Comment: Im making a function call cDump to dump a bunch of firefox objects and stuff, it really helps me make my addons. You can see me working on it here: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9033922 the function im working on is cDumpNeo, I used to use cDumpClassic, but it got real hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. It won't be sent as it is in the method call.

```
getVarName("var");

function getVarName(variableName) {
  /* this would be var */
}
```

The function has its own parameter for that variable. However, you can get the value in that variable.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't how variables work in JavaScript.

If you want to maintain a mapping of strings to values, use an object:

```
values = { myVar: 'this is a string' }
```

Comment: Thanks I know that but the issue is I'm making some debug functions to "pretty print" stuff. I know theres custom ones out there, but it doesnt work in firefox addons the way I need it to. Is there any other way with the latest ES versions?

Answer (score 0):

I know you have mentioned you don't want objects to be involved. But have a look at this one:

```js
const getVarName = (variable) => {
  let varName = '';
  for (let key in variable) varName = key;
  return varName;
}

const myVar = 'some string';

// Place your string inside curly braces
const nameOfVar = getVarName({myVar}); 

console.log(nameOfVar); // output: 'myVar'
```